# VSCode: Select entire function definition?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, code-navigation

Is there a way to select an entire function definition in VSCode?
That's a recurring action in my dev workflow, and I'd like to automate it instead of using my mouse. Couldn't find a shortcut for it. Surely there ought to be a way?

I'm using python/javascript as my languages, with Python (ms-python.python) & JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly (ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) extensions installed.

Thank you!

Comment: use the folding arrows in the left-gutter, when function collapsed select that line, it depends on the language what a function is and how to separate them, you need to build an AST from the text and the language server does this to determine the fold arrows

Comment: Nice! That works!
Want to post that as an answer so that I can upvote and mark resolved? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the folding arrows in the left-gutter.

When function collapsed select that line and Copy

It depends on the language what a function is and how to separate them, you need to build an AST from the text and the language server does this to determine the fold arrows.

Comment: Be sure to select the WHOLE collapsed line. You must select to the beginning of the next line below the collapsed lines. I didn't think collapsed select thing worked at first, till I realized the issue. Simply double clicking to select the visible portion of the collapsed lines doesn't seem to be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The VS Code VIM extension has bindings `vii` and `vai` to select by indentation level (see github documentantion https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim?tab=readme-ov-file#vim-indent-object) .

This implies that you can then select the function as long as you're at the first indentation level of the function, but it would not select only the full function if the cursor is at the second indentation level or at the declaration of the function.

This could maybe be an alternative to the fold select method of the other answer when the cursor is not at the function declaration.